# Создание снимка с RTSP потока видео камеры

Tags: python, ffmpeg, видео, vlc, rtsp

Нужно написать скрипт/программу для создания снимка с определённого RTSP потока. Средствами чего это лучше реализовать: то есть я понимаю что можно использовать python + VLC или python + ffmpeg. Просьба подсказать самый быстрый и лёгкий путь.

Comment: почему вы хотите именно Питон здесь использовать? Есть обёртки для ffmpeg типа [pyav](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV/blob/master/examples/save_frames.py), [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20891936/4279).

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://host/path/stream -frames 1 -f image2 snapshot.jpg
```

а дальше уже это звать из нужного места. Насчёт привязок (bindings) семейства библиотек avXXX для Python я не знаю, но и использовать это будет сложнее.

Comment: серые кадры так могут появляться, надо пропустить парочку фреймов

Comment: Нужно подождать ключевого кадра (или I-frame). Вроде есть для этого опция.

Comment: В ffmpeg не нашёл(хотя не сильно искал) - сделал пропуск полсекунды.